# How can I replace all hex using RegEx in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, hex

So I've been toying around with Regular Expressions, and my friend challenged me to write a script that replaced all hex within a string. He gave me a large file mixed with different characters and, of course, some hex strings.

Each occurrence of hex is preceded with `\x`, so for example: `\x55`.

I thought it'd be pretty easy, so I tried out this pattern on some online regex tester: `/\\x([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/`

It worked perfectly.

However, when I throw it into some PHP code, it fails to replace it at all.

Can anyone give me a nudge into the right direction of where I'm going wrong?

Here's my code:

```
$toDecode = file_get_contents('hex.txt');
$pattern = "/\\x(\w{2})/";
$replacement = 'OK!';

$decoded = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $toDecode);

$fh = fopen('haha.txt', 'w');
fwrite($fh, $decoded);
fclose($fh);
```

Comment: Can you please provide a small snippet of your file `hex.txt`?

Comment: True hex only includes the characters `0-9` and `A-F`, while your regular expression will match characters other than these.

Comment: Good call, nick. I'll change that in a moment.

Comment: You could improve your recognition - `\w` is any letter or number, but hex is only 0-9 and A-F.  You could replace it with [0-9a-fA-F]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have not escaped your backslashes in the PHP string. It needs to be:

```
$pattern = "/\\\\x(\\w{2})/";
```

<strike>...or:</strike>

```
$pattern = '/\\x(\w{2})/';
```

...with single quotes.
<sup>- *This actually suffers the same problem and requires the full double-escaped sequence*</sup>

But `\w` will match any perl word character, which is not just hex characters. I would use the character class `[a-fA-F0-9]` instead.

Comment: All this escaping gives me a headache, but that was indeed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

```
<?php
  // grab the encoded file
  $toDecode = file_get_contents('hex.txt');

  // create a method to convert \x?? to it's character facsimile
  function escapedHexToHex($escaped)
  {
    // return 'OK!'; // what you're doing now
    return chr(hexdec($escaped[1]));
  }

  // use preg_replace_callback and hand-off the hex code for re-translation
  $decoded = preg_replace_callback('/\\\\x([a-f0-9]{2})/i','escapedHexToHex', $toDecode);

  // save result(s) back to a file
  file_put_contents('haha.txt', $decoded);
```

For reference, [preg_replace_callback](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). Also, don't use `\w` as it's actually translated to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`. Hex  is base-16, so you want `[a-fA-F0-9]` (and the `i` flag makes it case-insensitive).

[Working example](http://ideone.com/U16Je), minus the file part.

Comment: wouldn't `preg_replace($pattern, chr(hexdec($1)), $toDecode)` have the same effect?

Comment: @Rob: Supposedly, though I had [trouble getting it to work](http://ideone.com/lWv3z) (even while using the `e` flag)

Comment: as did I. very strange. yours does indeed work, but now I want to know why my example above doesn't. Time to toy around with that. Thanks for the help!